# Is it possible to observe Polaris and the Southern Cross from the equator during an equinox

Tags: constellations

Is it possible for an observer at Earth's equator to simultaneously observe Polaris and the Southern Cross during an equinox?

Comment: It's hard to view Polaris at the equator since it's only a fractional degree above the horizon at best. There are plenty of places you can see both, even in locations as far north as Key West, Florida.

Answer (score 6):

The March equinox would be a good time to see both; the September equinox would not.
[Crux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crux)
lies roughly between RA 12h to 13h, Dec -55$^\circ$ to -65$^\circ$.
For best results, be at latitude 10-15$^\circ$ N so that both Crux and Polaris are well above the horizon, and look between 11:00 and 14:00 local
[sidereal time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidereal_time)
so that Crux is near the meridian.
That would be around midnight in March-April, late evening in May, wee hours in February, or daytime in July-December.